# Apache CXF conduit matching strategy

Tags: spring, cxf

Maybe anyone knows how does Apache CXF match HTTP conduits, configured in Spring? I mean, here is the conduit definition:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://abc.com/wsdl}MyPortHttp.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive" MaxRetransmits="1" ReceiveTimeout="180000" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

What happens if I omit `.http-conduit` part? Where is the code of actual matching? My quick search has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done mostly in `org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory#configure(Object, String, String)`. Then it dispatches to `org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(String, Object, boolean)`. If you omit `.http-conduit` part, configuration will not be visible for CXF, as it has very simple matching behavior: by wildcard, or by conduit name (`org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getBeanName()` contains hardcoded `.http-conduit` suffix).

Also, I've faced a strange behavior when wildcard conduit overrides port-specific one. Check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4763) issue.